# Python: find a duplicate in a container efficiently

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, duplicates

I have a container `cont`. If I want to find out if it has duplicates, I'll just check `len(cont) == len(set(cont))`.

Suppose I want to find a duplicate element if it exists (just any arbitrary duplicate element). Is there any neat and efficient way to write that?

[Python 3]

Comment: Your method IS efficient! =) It is `O(N)` time and space (best you can do since `x in myList` is `O(N)`, see http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity ). There are ways to improve the space-efficiency for a minor hit to time-efficiency (e.g. bloom filters). The other way you can significantly improve is to return instantly on certain kinds of lists, e.g. [0,1,1,2,3,4,5,...]. This assumed a bit about the distribution of your lists (for example do you optimize for this case, or duplicated at the end, or both?), but can be a worthwhile optimization since it doesn't affect asymptotic speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, my first answer has gotten quite a bit of flack, so I thought I'd try a few different ways of doing this and report the differences. Here's my code.

```
import sys
import itertools

def getFirstDup(c, toTest):

    # Original idea using list slicing => 5.014 s
    if toTest == '1':
        for i in xrange(0, len(c)):
            if c[i] in c[:i]:
                return c[i]

    # Using two sets => 4.305 s
    elif toTest == '2':
        s = set()
        for i in c:
            s2 = s.copy()
            s.add(i)
            if len(s) == len(s2):
                return i

    # Using dictionary LUT => 0.763 s
    elif toTest == '3':
        d = {}
        for i in c:
            if i in d:
                return i
            else:
                d[i] = 1

    # Using set operations => 0.772 s
    elif toTest == '4':
        s = set()
        for i in c:
            if i in s:
                return i
            else:
                s.add(i)

    # Sorting then walking => 5.130 s
    elif toTest == '5':
        c = sorted(c)
        for i in xrange(1, len(c)):
            if c[i] == c[i - 1]:
                return c[i]

    # Sorting then groupby-ing => 5.086 s
    else:
        c = sorted(c)
        for k, g in itertools.groupby(c):
            if len(list(g)) > 1:
                return k

    return None


c = list(xrange(0, 10000000))
c[5000] = 0

for i in xrange(0, 10):
    print getFirstDup(c, sys.argv[1])
```

Basically, I try this in six different ways, as listed in the source file. I used the Linux `time` command and collected the realtime runtimes, running the commands like so

```
time python ./test.py 1
```

with `1` being which algorithm I wanted to try. Each algorithm looks for the first duplicate in 10,000,000 integers, and runs ten times. There is one duplication in the list, which is "mostly sorted" though I did try reverse sorted lists without noticing a proportional difference between algorithms.

My original suggestion did poorly at 5.014 s. My understanding of icyrock.com's solution also did poorly at 4.305 s. Next I tried using a dictionary to create a LUT, which gave the best runtime at 0.763 s. I tried using the `in` operator on sets, and got 0.772 s, nearly as good as the dictionary LUT. I tried sorting and walking the list, which gave a pitiful time of 5.130 s. Finally, I tried John Machin's suggestion of the itertools, which gave a poor time of 5.086 s.

In summary, a **dictionary LUT** seems to be the way to go, with set operations (which may use LUTs in its implementation) being a close second.

---

Update: I tried razpeitia's suggestion, and apart from the fact that you need to know precisely what duplicate key you're looking for, the actual algorithm did the worst so far (66.366 s).

---

Update 2: I'm sure someone is going to say that this test is biased because the duplicate location is near one end of the list. *Try running the code* using a different location before downvoting and report your results!

Comment: That's a really bad way to test. You should put them each in their own function and use the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module. This will cut out stuff like startup time.

Comment: @aaronsterling: This wasn't meant to be particularly elegant. I'm more interested in general trends rather than specific times, plus I was sick of my first attempt getting downvoted by people who guessed that it was a bad algorithm, but had no data to back it up. This isn't great data, but it is data; next time I'll use the timeit module.

Comment: +1 for putting in the effort.  Don't take the downvotes personally, think of it as a learning experience!

Comment: For method 2, you didn't need to copy the whole set, just remember its length is enough. Method 6 is intended to solve a more difficult problem (find all duplicates). The make the test fair, don't put any duplicate element at all, and see how long it would take to return `None`. It's clear that methods 2, 3 and 4 are the only linear-time methods, so nothing else needs to be tested. In the end, on Python 3, I'm getting 2: 5.18s, 3: 2.22s, 4: 2.63s. Amazingly, set (which seems the natural solution) is 20% slower than dict.

Comment: @max: Good catch on method 2. After reviewing my methodology, I really should have tried a list with no duplicates, then one in the middle, and one at the end to get more realistic results. Oh well, maybe next time.

Comment: Your test only works with the duplicated item near the start of the very large list ... if you also tested with the iterator at different locations, it is illuminating:
`for location in (50,5000,50000,5000000):
    c = range(0,10000000)
    c[location] = 0`

Answer (score 7):

You can start adding them to the set and as soon as you try to add the element that is already in the set you found a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

It's not apparent what's the point of finding one arbitrary element that is a duplicate or 1 or more other elements of the collection ... do you want to remove it? merge its attributes with those of its twins / triplets / ... / N-tuplets? In any case, that's an O(N) operation, which if repeated until no more duplicates are detected is an O(N ** 2) operation.

However you can get a bulk deal at the algorithm warehouse: sort the collection -- O(N*log(N)) -- and then use `itertools.groupby` to bunch up the duplicates and cruise through the bunches, ignoring the bunches of size 1 and doing whatever you want with the bunches of size > 1 -- all of that is only about O(N).

Comment: Good point. In my case, it was just to report a duplicate (since it's supposed to raise an Exception). Hard to think of when one might want to do this otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import Counter

cont = [1, 2, 3]
c = Counter(cont)
x = someItem

if c[x] == 0:
    print("Not in cont")
elif c[x] == 1:
    print("Unique")
else:
    print("Duplicate")
```

Comment: `Counter` is only implemented from 2.7 onward if I recall correctly, with 2.5 or 2.6 you can use `defaultdict(int)` within a loop and increment it manually, though it's obviously less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You have to scan all the elements for the duplicates as they can be just the last ones you check, so you can't get more efficient than worst case O(N) time, just like linear search. But a simple linear search to find a duplicate will use up O(N) memory, because you need to track what you've seen so far.

If the array is sorted you can find duplicates in O(N) time without using any additional memory because duplicate pairs will be next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

If your container is a list, you can just pass the value you're looking for to its count() method and check the result:

```
>>> l = [1,1,2,3]
>>> l.count(1)
2
>>>
```

A dictionary can't have duplicate keys, nor can a set. Outside of these, I'd need to know what kind of container it is. I guess the real point is to always make sure you haven't missed an obvious solution to the problem before you go coding a custom solution. I fall prey to this myself sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

According to http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity most of the list operations are terribly inefficient (just confirmed that `x in myList` does seem to be `O(N)` in python3).

The method given by the original poster **is** efficient because it is O(N) time and space (this is the "best" you can, without making additional assumptions about your list, since list operations like  `x in myList` are `O(N)`).

There is a major optimization which is possible, which is to iteratively build up the set. This would return quickly on certain kinds of lists, e.g. `[0,1,1,2,3,4,5,...]`. However you are implicitly assuming a bit about the distribution of your lists (for example, do you optimize for this case, or optimize for duplicates at the end, or both?). The good thing about this optimization is that it doesn't affect asymptotic speed. Here's how I would code it elegantly:

```
def hasDuplicate(iter):
    visited = set()
    for item in iter:
        if item in visited:
            return True
        visited.add(item)
    return False
```

You could also return the first duplicate, but you can't return `None`; you'd have to raise an Exception since the iterable might contain `None`.

sidenote: There are ways to improve the space-efficiency for a minor hit to time-efficiency (e.g. bloom filters).

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestions, similar to jonesy's answer. At least in python3 (haven't tested in python 2.7), when c[-5000] = 0, this becomes faster than solution 3 and 4 of the original answer. Otherwise it is only slightly faster than solution 1 and 2...

```
elif toTest == '7':
    for i in c:
        if c.count(i)>1:
            return i
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
def getFirstDup(cont):
    for i in xrange(0, len(cont)):
        if cont[i] in cont[:i]:
            return cont[i]
    return None
```

Comment: Nice, but would possibly be better as a generator

Comment: @fmark: if he needed more than one duplicate, then yes, but his question leads me to believe he just wants the first duplicate.

Comment: not so nice.. only works with ordered containers, and who knows what amount of things will have to happen in order to slice the collection that much.

Comment: @Claudiu: I verified that it works with non-ordered containers as well. Please check my code before you downvote!

Comment: @Claudiu +1, still getting my head around the contracts involved with Python's container types.

Comment: -1 It's an O(N ** 2) operation just to find 1 duplicate and not even have a clue what it's a duplicate of??? Sheesh, the naive 2-for-loops algorithm that compares every possible pair takes only nC2 ie. n*(n-1)/2 comparisons

Comment: @John: It's O(n^2) worst case, but it will cease computation upon finding the first duplicate; if you expect the sequence to be dense with duplicates then it may perform better than some other solutions. That said, it isn't idiomatic Python at all.

Comment: @Zeke: `>>> b = set("ABCDEF")
>>> b[:4]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    b[:4]
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @Claudiu: This function is designed to take in lists, not sets. I guess "container" is a pretty broad descriptor; I wrote this function to handle lists without checking other container types.

Comment: @Zeke: so what did you mean when you said it works with non-ordered containers as well, if you only tested it with lists? did you mean sorted? sorted != ordered. ah also the question asks about containers in general, hence my downvote, since it only works on lists or other ordered containers (or to be even more specific, containers supporting slice notation).

Comment: @Claudiu: Fair enough, thanks for the clarification about the downvote. I was incorrectly using sorted as a synonym for ordered.